# How to generate a Mollweide projection of the rotated earth?

Tags: graphics

I can center an [orthographic projection of the earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_map_projection) over New Zealand with

```
GeoGraphics[GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" -> {-41, 174}}]
```

[image]

However, centering fails for the [Mollweide projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection):

```
GeoGraphics[GeoProjection -> {"Mollweide", "Centering" -> {-41, 174}}]
```

[image]

How can I generate a Mollweide projection of the earth centered over New Zealand?

Comment: `GeoGraphics[{}
 , GeoProjection -> {"Mollweide"
   , "Centering" -> GeoPosition[Entity["Country", "NewZealand"]]
   }
 , GeoGridLines -> Automatic
 , GeoRange -> "World"
 , GeoCenter -> Entity["Country", "NewZealand"]
 , ImageSize -> Large
 ]` ?

Comment: @Syed no, what you suggest is a perspective from a point above the equator at New Zealand's longitude. You have only centered the [longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude) but not the [latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude). I want to look at the globe from a point hovering directly above New Zealand, so that New Zealand appears at the center of the map (horizontally and vertically).

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but we can

- Create an `Image` of earth in the equirectangular projection.
- Transform the pixels of the image so that New Zealand is at the center.
- Use `GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", _}]` to project this image onto the map.

Here's the rotation transform, which is unnecessarily brute force: geoposition -> spherical coordinates -> Cartesian coordinates -> rotation -> spherical coordinates -> geoposition.

```
tfunc = FullSimplify[
  RotationTransform[α °, {-Sin[β °], Cos[β °], 0}], {α, β} ∈ Reals];

res = Simplify[{π/2 - #1, #2}/Degree & @@ 
    Rest[CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", 
      tfunc[CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
        {1, (90 - lat) °, lon °}]]]], {α, β, lat, lon} ∈ Reals];

With[{gp = {Mod[#1 - β, 360, -180], #2} & @@ Reverse[res]},
  geoRotate = Compile[
    {{α, _Real}, {β, _Real}, {lat, _Real}, {lon, _Real}}, 
    gp,
    CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]
];
```

Image of earth:

```
im = GeoImage["World", "StreetMapNoLabels", 
   GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", ImageSize -> 1024];
```

Location to center around:

```
loc = Entity["Country", "NewZealand"];

{x, y} = QuantityMagnitude[LatitudeLongitude[loc], "AngularDegrees"];
```

Transform to place New Zealand in the center in the equirectangular projection:

```
im2 = ImageForwardTransformation[im, geoRotate[x, y, #[[2]], #[[1]]] &, 
  DataRange -> {{-180, 180}, {-90, 90}}]
```

[image]

Mollweide projection:

```
GeoGraphics["World", GeoProjection -> "Mollweide", 
  GeoGridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 1024, 
  GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"Image", im2, "Projection" -> "Mollweide"}]
]
```

[image]